# Is there official API for google-maps driving navigation?

Tags: android, navigation, google-maps-api-3, driving-directions

I've found that on Google support driving navigation on latest Android. http://www.google.com/mobile/navigation/index.html

But, I can't find any kinds of API set to provide those kinds of functions. Is there navigation support API? or isn't it released yet?

I can't understand why it's not included on Ginger bread version. They said that Nexus S already support Driving navigation.

Do you have any information about this issue? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Check Getting the geopoints from google maps from [routing-driving-directions-on-android](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-part-1-get-the-route/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send intents to the navigation app to navigate to a location? Apparently it is not "officially" supported, however here is how you tell the navigation app to navigate to a location.

```
String url = "google.navigation:q=" + lat + ","
            + lng;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: No. I'm looking for real Android SDK/API like Google Maps Open API. For example, var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

Comment: I am afraid not. Google has not published any api for their navigation service. You could always look at the source code if you wanted.

Comment: So do I. Not yet imported into Android and iOS. Thanks.

Comment: It's May 2014, do you guys know of any API/service that have recently been released?